# An error occurred in Service Broker internal activation while trying to scan the user queue 'msdb.dbo.ExternalMailQueue'. for its status. Error: 1222

Tags: sql-server

I am getting this error while sending email from SQL Server. We are using amazon as SMTP  mail server.

> Error occurred in Service Broker internal activation while trying to scan the user queue  'msdb.dbo.ExternalMailQueue' for its status. Error: 1222, State: 56. Lock request time out period exceeded. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

I also try to use below setting to fix it, but we are stilling getting the same issue.

```
ALTER DATABASE [msdb] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
ALTER DATABASE [msdb] SET DISABLE_BROKER
SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'msdb'
ALTER DATABASE [msdb] SET ENABLE_BROKER
SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'msdb'
ALTER DATABASE [msdb] SET MULTI_USER
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_stop_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_status_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_start_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_status_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_queue_sp @queue_type = 'mail'
```